# How to write xpath assertion for the xml in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter to test the api transaction

Response:

```
<ProcessByAcctResult>&lt;Inquiry.IVR.OUT TraceId="1233"&gt;&lt;ResponseCode&gt;00&lt;/ResponseCode&gtgt;&lt;/Inquiry.IVR.OUT&gt;</ProcessByAcctResult>
```

My Response is given above..

I wanted to assert responseCode is 00 if not should make it fail on the performance test. How to write a xpath for this.. or else any other way also fine..

Currently i am storing the variable using Regex Extractor and REsponse Assertion to compare the value.. Any other better solution

Comment: why you have `&lt` and not `<` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you provided is not a valid XML therefore you're only limited to [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) configured like:

[image]

More information: [Response Assertions in JMeter 3.2 - New and Improved](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved)

However if you're getting a real XML just not able to properly copy and paste it and your response actually looks like:

```
<ProcessByAcctResult>
    <Inquiry.IVR.OUT TraceId="1233">
        <ResponseCode>00</ResponseCode>
    </Inquiry.IVR.OUT>
</ProcessByAcctResult>
```

Then you can use the following [XPath Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Assertion) configuration:

[image]